# mathematical VS logical operators precedence

Tags: programming-languages, logical-operators

why is it that in most programming languages the mathematical operators precedence is different from the logical operators precedence.

meaning: why is `x / y * z` evaluates to `( x / y ) * z` so that `/` has the same precedence as `*` but in logical operators `x || y && z` would evaluate to `x || ( y && z )` 
So, is there a logical reason for this distinction ( some hardware reason, optimization technique) or is it just the way programming language creators decided to make them??

Comment: Consider `x + y * z`. Arithmetic operators also have a precedence hierarchy.

Comment: Not a clue. I always bracket-away such stuff anyway.  I, (and anyone who is unfortunate enough to have to maintain/enhance my code), don't/doesn't  have to think too hard.

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm with you a 100% , but I can't come up with a reason for why aren't both have the same precedence.. they seem more like (/ and *) than (* and +) to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about programming. Ever worked with boolean algebra? AND has precedence over OR there too, and boolean algebra is from the 17th century (though I don't know when this convention came to be). The two are also written as * and +, which gives a clue in that regard (but can confuse in others).

Programming language designers just carried these precedence rules over, just like they carried over the precedence of arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just the way programming language creators decided to make them.

More specifically it is likely that a programmer would want the AND statement to be evaluated before OR, in the case of lack of parentheses.

In other words || is more like "addition or subtraction left to right " and && is more like "multiplication division left to right"

Also remember that ! (not) is of even higher precedence than && (AND)